# How to replace " into space or delete first and last symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, character

I get xml data and I get value from it.

I need to delete symbols [ and ]

Here is my code, that gives me error about undegined variable:

```
         @xml = XmlSimple.xml_in(res.content)//here I get xml document
         payKey = @xml["payKey"]//gere I get needed value
         //it looks like "[some character]" so I need to delete [ and ]
         //I tried
         payKey = @xml["payKey"].to_s()//to use tr method
         payKey = payKey.tr("[]", "")//replacing
        redirect_to "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=#{paykey}"//inserting into url
```

and result:

```
            svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey="AP-7NK73769LH704515X"
```

So I need to delete " signs. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer:

```
payKey = payKey[1..20]
```